# Aren't HANDLER supossed to have a Thread of their own?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm really frustrated now.

I'm trying to do a socket connection but I always get the NetworkOnMainThread Exception.

My goal is to create an object which has the thread, socket and Messenger model to comunicate using exclusively that object, like so:

```
WebBridge wb = new WebBridge(); 
wb.Send("My data to send", myLocalMessengerForAnswer);
```

I tried to use a Handler with the same result. Also I tried this, creating my own thread with a Handler of its own, but no success.

Aren't handler supossed to have their own Thread? Why am I getting the NetworkInMainThread Exception if I'm supposed to be in the Handler's thread?

Thanks in advance.

```
public class WebBridge {
    private class WebBridgeThread extends Thread {
    static final int STARTUP = 1;

    public Handler handler;
    Socket socket;

    public WebBridgeThread() {
        super("WebBridgeThread");
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Looper.prepare();
        handler = new Handler() {
            @Override
            public void dispatchMessage(Message msg) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.dispatchMessage(msg);
                switch(msg.what) {
                    case STARTUP:
                    try {
                        socket = new Socket("192.168.100.99",1234);
                        int fer = 5;
                    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
        Looper.loop();
    }


}


public WebBridge(Context paramContext) {
    WebBridgeThread wbt = new WebBridgeThread();
    wbt.start();
    Message msg = new Message();
    msg.what = WebBridgeThread.STARTUP;
    wbt.handler.dispatchMessage(msg);
}
```

Comment: dispatchMessage vs sendMessage ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why am I getting the NetworkInMainThread Exception if I'm supposed to be in the Handler's thread?

If you check the code for `Handler`, you will see that `dispatchMessage()` basically calls `handleMessage()`, which means **it runs on the current thread**, i.e. the UI thread in your case.

Instead, if you call `sendMessage()`, handler will enqueue the message and run the logic in `handleMessage()` on the thread with the looper, i.e. the background thread in your case. (Under the hood `Looper.loop()` calls directly `dispatchMessage()` after dequeueing a message from the queue; here the current thread is the thread with the looper)

**So you need to**:

1. Use `sendMessage()` in `WebBridge()` instead of `dispatchMessage()`
2. Override `handleMessage()` instead of `dispatchMessage()` in the `Handler`

Setting the thread priority to background would also be a good idea, so you won't race so much with the UI thread.

By the way, you could also use a `HandlerThread` which does the hard work for you, it creates a new thread and sets its priority. Then, after you start it, you can get its looper (`getLooper()`) and push it in the constructor of a handler. You still need to override `handleMessage()` in the handler for your network logic.

Comment: Had to add this, according to android documentation: "Each Handler instance is associated with a single thread and that thread's message queue. **When you create a new Handler, it is bound to the thread / message queue _of the thread that is creating it_**.

Guess I didn't catch that part!